# I want a dataframe with .loc [ ] from pandas in python with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select some specific rows from this dataframe:

```
df   Name Book
1    a1    a2
2    b1    b2
3    c1    c2
4    d1    d2
```

I have a variable `result` which contains the generated numbers from the first to the last row in the dataframe.
Now I try it with 
`df_new=df.loc[result,:]`
which gives me an error. When I use the df without the book column it works, but `df_new` only includes the first column. I don't have a clue on how to make it return multiple columns whilst selecting specific rows.
Example of what I want:

```
df_new Name Book
2      b1    b2
3      c1    c2
```

What I have/get:

```
df_new Name
2      b1
3      c1
```

Comment: ```df.set_index('df').loc[[2,3]]``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
start = 1
end = 2
df.loc[start:end,:]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your answer - and though it might answer the question, it would have been a better answer if you provided and explanation of the solution you are suggesting. Learn more about writing good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a comma which tells `.loc` you are switching to selecting columns.

So `df.loc[result:]` would already do the trick.

Or, you could explicitly give a range which includes all columns: `df.loc[result:, :]`

Have a look at `pandas`' docs for [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to learn more!

> Allowed inputs are:
>
> - A single label, e.g. `5` or `'a'`, (note that `5` is interpreted as a *label* of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
> - A list or array of labels, e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
> - A slice object with labels, e.g. `'a':'f'`.
>
> > Warning
> >
> > Note that contrary to usual python slices, both the start and the stop are included
>
> - A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. `[True, False, True]`.
> - A `callable` function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just cant get my head around how this works even with the documentation. But now I get the following error message:'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'set'.